# counting how many times is repeating a character using from an other table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have to display for every athlete the number of races that he had participated in and the athletes that have participated in every race. I am trying to use the left join and count but always l have field.

Below is a Table structure:-

```
Athlete (A_ID, A_NAME, A_SURNAME, SQUAD_NAME, NATIONALITY)  
PRIMARY KEY=A_ID

RACE(R_ID, R_NAME, R_TYPE, CATEGORY)  
PRIMARY KEY=R_ID

PARTICIPATION(R_ID, A_ID, POSITION)   

R_ID and A_ID are foreign keys but are used as a primary key in `PARTICIPATION` table
```

Any help would be appreciated:
I have to display for every athlete the umber of races that him participated and the athletes that have participated in every race. I am trying to use the left join and count but always l have field. 
I have to create a trigger that each time the position change it block the duplicate of that position in the same race and the position value dont have to pass the actual value

have to write a function that takes the race id and return the number of athletes that have participated.

Comment: MySQL or plsql is tagged wrong here as MySQL and Oracle database (plsql) are not the same, please check it.. And also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please remove wrong tags and post the code you tried, so that people can help you in editing it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain more clearly the results you require.

Comment: It's not clear at all, what you are asking: "*display for every athlete the number of races that he had participated in and the athletes that have participated in every race*" - That sounds like two different results, and thus should be two separate questions. "*have to write a function that takes the race id and return the number of athletes that have participated*" - That sounds like a third question. And the title "*counting how many times is repeating a character using from an other table in sql*" is telling a completely different story.

Comment: Look if this helps you in an way it is our table with example data. It has all the data you requested in one table https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2274ee15870f547a3e3b0260c80436d7

Answer (score 0):

I created this codes but dont know if those are correct but both compiles

*for every athlete the number of races that him participated

```
'SELECT ATHLETE.A_NAME, COUNT(PARTICIPATION.G_ID) 
 FROM ATHLETE
 left JOIN PARTICIPATION
 ON ATHLETE.A_ID=PARTICIPATION.A_ID
 GROUP BY PARTICIPATION.G_ID
 HAVING COUNT (PARTICIPATION.G_ID)>1
 ORDER BY ATHLETE.A_NAME;'
```

turn the athletes that have participated in every race

```
SELECT ATHLETE.A_NAME
FROM ATHLETE
LEFT JOIN PARTICIPATION ON ATHLETE.A_ID=PARTICIPATION.A_ID
LEFT JOIN RACE ON RACE.R_ID=PARTICIPATION.R_ID
GROUP BY PARTICIPATION.A_ID
HAVING COUNT (PARTICIPATION.A_ID)=COUNT (RACE.R_ID)
ORDER BY ATHLETE.A_NAME
```